# APM server did not respond within 10s of gzip stream finish

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

I keep seeing the following error message in my ECK cluster:

```
[buyerportal-0 buyerportal] {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-05-19T06:46:40.752Z","log":{"logger":"elastic-apm-node"},"ecs":{"version":"1.6.0"},"message":"APM Server transport error (503): Unexpected APM Server response when polling config\nAgent configuration infrastructure is not ready. Please retry later."}
```

**Kibana version**: 8.7.1

**Elasticsearch version**: 8.7.1

**APM Server version**: 8.7.1

What's the root cause? How to resolve it?